# Using spark_apply in sparklyr to add weighted random normal vectors to multiple DF columns

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I'm new to sparklyr and I'm trying to add random normal vectors weighted by another vector to a large number of columns of a spark df. This is an example I've tried with mtcars.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc1 <- spark_connect(master = "local")

mtc_df = select(mtcars, vs:carb)
mtc_sdf = sdf_copy_to(sc1, mtc_df, name = "mtc_sdf", overwrite = TRUE)

tf_df <- function(df1){
    df1 %>%
        mutate_at(vars(am:carb), funs(. + vs * rnorm(32, 100, 1)))
}

tf_df(mtc_df) # works 

mtc_sdf %>%
    spark_apply(function(d) tf_df(d), memory = TRUE) # doesn't work
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\....\filea54a7656c3_spark.log': Permission denied
```

I also tried to adapt the example on https://spark.rstudio.com/ but got the same error.

```
mtc_sdf %>%
    spark_apply(function(data) {
        data[2:4] + data[1]*rnorm(32*3,100,1)
    })
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try giving full (or write) permissions to log directory?
This will allow you to use logs and identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding How would I change log permission in R - I've haven't done it before? What do you mean by 'add vs' ?

Comment: Can you execute as admin or root to see if that has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to add random normal vectors weighted by another vector to a large number of columns of a spark df

I would recommend skipping `spark_apply` and using Spark's own `randn` ([which gives](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@randn():org.apache.spark.sql.Column) ~N(0, 1)):

```
mtc_sdf %>% mutate_at(vars(am:carb), funs(. + vs * (randn() * 1 + 100)))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
# Database: spark_connection
      vs        am     gear      carb
   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     0   1.00000   4.0000   4.00000
 2     0   1.00000   4.0000   4.00000
 3     1 101.36894 103.1954  98.80757
 4     1 100.79066 102.6765 100.91702
 5     0   0.00000   3.0000   2.00000
 6     1 100.07964 103.1568 100.54303
 7     0   0.00000   3.0000   4.00000
 8     1 101.90050 103.0402 101.46825
 9     1  99.63565 103.7781 101.65752
10     1  99.72587 102.3854 105.09205
```

Regarding your code:

- Problem you experience looks like permission issue. Please make sure that Spark user has all required permission and `winutilis` are properly used.
- Function used with `spark_apply`:

  > transforms a data frame partition into a data frame.

  So you cannot hard code number of rows. You should rather use something like `rnorm(nrow(df1), 100, 1))`.
- `sparklyr` doesn't seem to properly serialize functions referenced by name so you might have to inline the function or wrap it in a package:

  ```
  mtc_sdf %>% 
    spark_apply(function(df) dplyr::mutate_at(
      df, dplyr::vars(am:carb), dplyr::funs(. + vs * rnorm(nrow(df), 100, 1))))
  ```

  ```
  # Source:   table<sparklyr_tmp_34ce7faa2d33> [?? x 4]
  # Database: spark_connection
        vs        am     gear      carb
     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
   1     0   1.00000   4.0000   4.00000
   2     0   1.00000   4.0000   4.00000
   3     1 100.59678 101.9111 100.99830
   4     1  98.87146 104.8058  99.20102
   5     0   0.00000   3.0000   2.00000
   6     1  99.38243 102.8664 100.37921
   7     0   0.00000   3.0000   4.00000
   8     1  98.99019 103.4996 101.69110
   9     1  99.33687 102.3849 103.38833
  10     1 100.02103 104.9381 102.07139
  # ... with more rows
  ```

  Also please not that packages from the driver are not attached automatically so you have to do it manually or reference library functions using fully qualified names.

Comment: That works, great! Inlining the function and explicitly referencing dplyr made the difference.

Also, you're right that randn() is better. It runs many times faster.

I think my permissions error is a problem for debugging rather than running spark.

Thanks very much!